# drawImage is not drawing

Tags: java, user-interface, drawimage

so this is basically how my code is working

```
class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable {

   public Main() {
      //init everything
   }

   public void start() {
      running = true;
      Thread thread = new Thread(this);
      thread.start();
   }

   public void run() {
      while(running) {
         render();
      }
   }

   public void render() {
      Image dbImage  = createImage(width, height);
      Graphics dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
      draw(dbg);
      Graphics g = getGraphics();
      g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
      g.dispose();
   }

   public void draw(Graphics g) {
      for(int y=0; y < map.length; y++) {
         for(int x=0; x < map.length; x++) {
            g.drawImage(map.map[x + y* map.MAP_DIM], x*MAP_DIM, y*MAP_DIM, this);
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String... args) {
      Main main = new Main();
      main.start();
   }
}
```

but nothing gets drawn, all i see is gray. anyone know what the problem could be? i tried doing repaint() at the end of the draw() method, but still nothing.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks). Also, Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Read the tutorials before doing this sort of coding, else you'll risk making all the wrong assumptions and creating non-functioning code like you've posted above.

Comment: ya ill take a look at the tutorials

Comment: Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for some more useful tips.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to manage drawing by yourself with Swing in Java.

You must let the [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) thread call the appropriate repaint methods by its own thread. This is done by invoking `JComponent`'s `paint(Graphics g)`. Now you shouldn't override that method but `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead.

So you should move your draw method from the thread to the appropriate draw method:

```
public void run() {
  while (running)
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  draw(g);
}
```

Mind that you should call the repaint at a fixed frame rate and use double buffering to avoid flickering.

An even simpler solution would be to embed something already prepared for this kind of work, like a [Processing](http://processing.org) frame, which works very well.

Comment: `use double buffering to avoid flickering` ... Swing components are double buffered by default ... not that one should avoid the subject as the default mechanism may not always meet ones needs though ;) +1 from me