# Getting a NullPointerException from Graphics.drawImage in Java

Tags: java, graphics, nullpointerexception, drawimage

I'm getting a NullPointerException when calling drawImage() on the last line of this sample even though I'm not giving it a null variable. Help would be appreciated.

```
    BufferedImage image = null;
    System.out.println(image);

    try {

        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/gameobjects/diaz.jpg"));
        System.out.println("eter");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(image);
    Graphics g = mainPanel.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 50, 50, null);
```

and the stack trace:

```
null
eter
BufferedImage@6a5f6303: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@1c5d9084 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 384 height = 216 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:41)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Comment: Please indicate which line is line 41 of `Main.java`.

Comment: We need to see your main method.

Comment: I would think it is the graphics 'g' that is null -- the exception doesn't come from the drawImage method, but from your method.  Test 'g' for null.

Comment: `getGraphics` may be returning `null`.  If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171825/null-pointer-exception-on-getgraphics.

Comment: Line 41 is the last line in the sample I gave.

Comment: Thanks.  In that case, `g` is null.  See my previous comment.

Comment: Inside the constructor of `Main` class it seems, at `line 41`. What is being used that is `null`? Stop taking the `graphics` reference by calling `getGraphics()` instead override `paintComponent()` of a `JPanel/JComponent` and draw image in that method, by using the `Graphics` object received from `Swing` as cited in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230)

Comment: where's mainPanel definition?

Comment: where/how is declared `mainPanel` ?

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to change `"/gameobjects/diaz.jpg"` to `"gameobjects/diaz.jpg'` without the leading '/'. If so it's because of relative resource paths as compared to absolute resource paths. '/' specifies absolute, so it's looking for C:/game... (on windows) rather than /game...

Comment: That should not be the cause of the problem.  If it causes `image` to be `null`, that might cause a `NullPointerException` somewhere inside `drawImage`, **not** on the line that calls `drawImage`.  Plus you're making baseless assumptions about the questioner's directory setup and environment.